# How do I easily Collection information from the Visual Studio immediate window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection, collections

Sometimes execute a ToList() on a collection and it doesn't return much useful information. How can I get useful information from collections and child collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would be nice to be able to use LINQ in the immediate window I haven't seen a reliable solution as of yet.  It sure would be nice. However, if you need some information quickly you can use the following extension methods. Unfortunately this won't filter your lists.

```
  public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static List<String> PropertyNames(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        var items = list.OfType<Object>();
        return items.Any()
            ? items.First().GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
            : new List<string>();
    }

    public static List<Object> Peek(this IEnumerable list, String name)
    {
        var data = from object item in list let property = item.GetType()
                   .GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public) 
               where property != null select property.GetValue(item, null);
        return data.OfType<Object>().ToList();
    }
}
```

You can then start getting info as follows in the immediate window:
(Don't forget extension method references)

```
myList.Peek("CustomObject"); // Get a list of CustomObject child property.
```

And if you need the properties.

```
myList.Properties() // Get a list of property names.
```

And you can chain them fine.

```
myList.Peek("CustomObject").PropertyNames(); // Get names => Found "Height" property.
myList.Peek("CustomObject").Peek("Height");  // Get a list of heights.
```